# How to use Craft commands in Github Actions

Tags: deployment

This is how I want to trigger certain actions with the craft terminal.

It does not work:

```
# execute Craft commands on remote server
  - name: Execute SSH Craft Commands on remote server
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
      script: |
        ./craft project-config/apply
```

> err: bash: ./craft: No such file or directory

If I try

```
craft project-config/apply
```

or (as written in some tutorials)

```
php craft project-config/apply
```

I get:

> out: Could not open input file: craft

What's the correct syntax here? If I do `./craft` manually on the server it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the command inside the proeject root. The `craft` executable isn't available in your `$PATH` since it's not a globally installed tool, but just a [PHP file that's located in the project root](https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/main/craft).

Those two commands are just two ways to call this executable:

- `php craft` runs the `craft` file with PHP (the version that's linked on the CLI). The `craft` in this command in just a relative file path in this case.
- `./craft` executes the `craft` binary directly, the OS knows to execute it with PHP due to the [shebang](https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/main/craft#L1). The `./craft` is a relative path to the file.

Due to the way those commands work, they will only function correctly when executed in the project root.

Github actions are executed in the project root by default, but the SSH connection will go to the home directory of the user you're connecting to. This probably isn't the project root, so you either need to use absolute paths or change the working directory as the first command in your action:

```bash
cd /path/to/project/root
```

Put this command as the first part of your `script`, then it should work correctly.

Comment: Nice. In that case I just use `cd ${{ secrets.SERVER_LIVE_PATH }}`.
Thank you